# Como implementar o cordova-plugin-accountkit no meu projeto cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, apache-cordova, plugin

pesquisei por exemplos mas não achei nada pra elucidar minha dúvida, não tenho experiência com cordova (talvez por isso não saiba usar o `cordova-plugin-accountkit`).

esse é o código do arquivo `index.js` (praticamente do jeito que foi baixado):

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

//código do account kit que eu não sei o que fazer com ele

    loginWithPhoneNumber: function(options, onSuccess, onFailure) {
        options = {
            defaultCountryCode: "BR",
            facebookNotificationsEnabled: true,
            initialPhoneNumber: ["55", "123456789"]
        };
        function sucess(params){
            console.log(params);
        }
        function failure(params){
            console.log(params);
        }
        AccountKitPlugin.loginWithPhoneNumber(options, onSuccess, onFailure);
    },

   },
};

app.initialize();
```

só queria saber como deve ficar meu arquivo `index.js` e como chama-lo no `index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi mudando o plugin usei este e só precisei da documentação;

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook-account-kit

deixei a minha pergunta aqui caso alguém encontre o mesmo problema.

Comment: Marque a resposta como uma solução para o problema... =D